# API Telegram Bot: Bad Request: message can't be deleted

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram

Данная ошибка возникает при вызове метода `deleteMessage`
Для работы с данным методом требуется 2 параметра `chat_id` и `message_id`
Получив ответ сервера с нужным номером сообщения и id чата, я пытаюсь удалить это сообщение. На что мне выводит ошибку **400 Bad Request: message can't be deleted**

В чем может быть проблема? ID чата и номер сообщения верные. ***Я хочу удалять сообщения которые я отсылаю боту.*** Неужели бот не может удалять мои сообщения в нашем общем чате? Возможно ли решить данную проблему или так и засорять чат ненужными сообщениями. Я хочу что б в чате была только актуальная информация и моя команда удалялась перед тем как бот отправит сообщение в ответ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В соответствии с [документацией](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#deletemessage), метод **deleteMessage** имеет следующие ограничения:

> - A message can only be deleted if it was sent less than 48 hours ago.
> - Bots can delete outgoing messages in groups and supergroups.
> - Bots granted can_post_messages permissions can delete outgoing messages in channels.
> - If the bot is an administrator of a group, it can delete any message there.
> - If the bot has can_delete_messages permission in a supergroup or a channel, it can delete any message there. Returns True on success.

В приватных чатах бот не может удалять сообщения.

Comment: ну да, давно уже разобрался, но спасибо,

Answer (score 0):

Я вышел из такой ситуации, что я меняю сообщение на "удалено", вместо самого сообщения

Comment: меняете сообщение вмеcто самого сообщения? я вижу какую-то логическую несостыковку в таким образом построенной фразе.